# replace braces with contents inside

Tags: java, regex

is it possible to `.replaceAll()` so that :

INPUT>

```
asd fs#{FIRST}l sdfj s#{SECOND}ijfio s#{THIRD}df o#{1}sj
```

OUTPUT>

```
asd fsFIRSTl sdfj sSECONDijfio sTHIRDdf o#{1}sj
```

This `#\{[A-Za-z]+\}` finds the whole **#{aaa}** but I don't want to delete the text inside..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course, you can make use of `capture groups`: -

```
String str = "asd fs#{FIRST}l sdfj s#{SECOND}ijfio s#{THIRD}df o#{1}sj";
str = str.replaceAll("#\\{([A-Za-z]+)\\}", "$1");
```

If you want any explanation for this, do ask. I think, the code is self-explanatory.